# How to set title attribute for option elements in a select bound to a model with AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a select element in my html bound to an ng-model.

Something like this example:

```
<select data-ng-model="accountType" data-ng-options="at.name for at in accountTypes">  </select>
```

My accountTypes would look like this:

```
accountTypes:[
   { name:'Individual', value: 1, title: 'Individual Account'},  
   { name: 'Joint', value: 2, title: 'Joint Account'}
];
```

How can I achieve the final markup to look like this once the model is bound:

```
<option value="1" title="Individual Account">Individual</option>
<option value="2" title"Joint Account">Joint</option>
```

PS: jQuery hacks appreciated but my ideal solution would something (jQuery, DOM-modification)less.

Comment: What do you need the `title` for (use case + what you're intention is)? Angular will not even add your `value` to the DOM but instead keep a local hash of your values. Even if your value is "England", Angular will convert it to `0` or wherever it is in the Array. It will just associate that value with your Model and you can grab your data safely.

Comment: I just want to take advantage of the title attr. Is a well supported attribute and provides a helpful visual information when desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ngOptions doesn't currently support *title*.  Instead, use a ngRepeat on an options tag, or (harder) extend ngOptions to support your needs.

```
<select ng-model="accountType">
    <option ng-repeat="at in accountTypes" value="{{ at.value }}" title="{{ at.title }}"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Doesn't look bad. Would that still keep my model up to date when option selection changes?

Comment: @jsicary  did anyone every get this working with an object array as in the original question?  I tried and everything works but I cannot get the selected option.   See http://jsfiddle.net/jerrykur/BhESQ/

Comment: This breaks in Angular 1.4+ because of their change from `==` to `===`

Comment: Works in FF but not in Chrome